# .NET Google Calendar API Get Event's Color

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

I'm learning the .NET Google Calendar API and I can't find out how to get the event's color (not the calendar's). it's a relatively new function Google added. In the end of this code I'm trying to print out the title, start time and **color** of each event.

```
    {
        CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("calService");
        myService.setUserCredentials("me@gmail.com", "password");
        EventQuery myQuery = new EventQuery("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/me@gmail.com/private/full");
        myQuery.StartTime = new DateTime(2011, 10, 5);
        myQuery.EndTime = new DateTime(2011, 10, 7);

        EventFeed myResultsFeed = myService.Query(myQuery);
        Console.WriteLine("events:\n");
        foreach (EventEntry entry in myResultsFeed.Entries)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text + entry.Times[0].StartTime "\n");
        }
    }
```

where can I find the color ?

Isaac.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick perusal of Google's API Documentation, it appears that color is associated with the `CalendarEntry` class.  For instance, here's an example setting up a CalendarEntry and setting the color:

```
CalendarEntry calendar = new CalendarEntry();
calendar.Title.Text = "Little League Schedule";
calendar.Summary.Text = "This calendar contains the practice schedule and game times.";
calendar.TimeZone =  "America/Los_Angeles";
calendar.Hidden = false;
calendar.Color = "#2952A3";
calendar.Location = new Where("", "", "Oakland");
```

From reading about inserting the events, it looks like when you insert an event you specify a calendar feed, such as the [allcalendars feed](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#RetrievingCalendars) and the event is inserted into whichever calendar you specify via the URL, which leads me to assume that the color your event will take on will be the color that's set for that calendar.

Thus, assuming this to be correct, if you wanted events to be a certain color you'd have to first create a calendar that color and then add the events to that calendar.  Browsing the [.NET API Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) should get you the rest of the information you need in order to accomplish this.

Comment: thank you  for the effort. you're right about the color defined by the calendar the event belongs to, but what I'm trying to do is get the event color, which can be defined independently. you can have a look at it in a Google calendar, by clicking on the event. you'll see a down arrow to choose a color. it's important for me cause' that's how I work with the calendar and I need to interpret the color to a property value.

Comment: I see - sorry for misinterpreting your question.  I was also trying to see whether there was a way to get to the calendar an event belonged to in order to determine or set its color but the documentation isn't exactly amazing...

Comment: thanks again... I know, the documentation isn't friendly...the weird thing is that Google itself didn't implement this function in the mobile view (nor other App developer). although my intentions are desktop app...

Comment: I still don't know how to set an individual event to a special color, or if the API will let you, but I finally found class documentation rather than just the "developers guide" - http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/docs/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently updated their API as well as their .NET library. At time of writing this, the .NET library is still in Beta and I can't find any documentation specific to the .Net library. Using my Object Browser I can see that the Event class object now has a property called ColorId.

Here's a link to the generic documentation:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that... I've been waiting a long time for them to improve their API. the documentation is still useless though...but it's good to know it's possible now, and I'm sure I can find the way.